# Is it possible to slow down Javascript Interpreter on purpose?

Tags: javascript, performance, testing

I want to make my browser to execute javascript code slower. Is there a Browser addon or something to do this?

**Background**: I want to demonstrate the impact of execution time on a given browser game. The speed of this game is only limited by the speed of the execution time of its code, just like in the good old MS-DOS Games. To show students the impact of such coding (depending on CPU cycles and not on time), it would be great if I could throttle down the execution speed of the code.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can [underclock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underclocking) your processor.

Comment: couldn't you just write code to deliberately waste time?

Comment: You could run a CPU-intensive task next to the browser (some benchmarking tool, for example) or you might look into a way to throttle a specific process, but that depends on the operating system you’re using.

Comment: Maybe it's enough to run it in a virtual machine giving very few resources to it. For example Virtual Box allows to set the CPU execution cap for specific machine - http://superuser.com/questions/265322/limiting-cpu-speed-in-a-virtual-machine

Comment: I think a timer is what are you looking for. Check jquery's animate for a old but good example http://blog.bigbinary.com/2010/01/25/how-animate-really-works-in-jquery-simple-animation-case-discussed.html

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an appropriate use case for an actual [sleep function in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951021/1048572) - just put a busy loop in your code that runs until the time changes.

```
function sleep(µs) {
     var end = performance.now() + µs/1000;
     while (end > performance.now()) ; // do nothing
}
```

Comment: @Mathletics: Because [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) has micro-second accuracy. But you're right…

Comment: Naming a value after its units seems like a poor idea. µs/1000 is not the same as (x/1000)µs

Answer (score 1):

This code will draw/loop as fast as possible

```
function loop() {
  draw();
  loop();
}
```

This code will artificially add ~100 ms of time to each loop cycle

```
function loop() {
  draw();
  setTimeout(loop, 100);
}
```

Something I use when I create loops like this is a delta so accurate calculations can be made

```
function draw(delta) {
  console.log("%f ms", delta);
}

function loop(last) {
  var now = performance.now();
  var delta = now - last;
  draw(delta);
  setTimeout(function() { loop(now); }, 100);
}

loop(0);

// 102.51500000001397 ms
// 102.38000000000466 ms
// 105.33499999996275 ms
// 101.27500000002328 ms
// 103 ms
// 100.88000000000466 ms
// 100.9649999999674 ms
// 100.69500000000698 ms
// 102.01500000001397 ms
// 105.85499999998137 ms
```

As you can see, draw is being called about once every 100 ms. This is approximately 10 frames per second. You can now use this delta to do precise calculations for things like animation sequences or positioning moving elements

You could easily make this a variable for your loop

```
function framesPerSecond(x) {
  return 1e3/x;
}

function draw(delta) {
  console.log("%f ms", delta);
}

function loop(fps, last) {
  var now = performance.now();
  var delta = now - last;
  draw(delta);
  setTimeout(function() { loop(fps, now); }, fps);
}

loop(framesPerSecond(25), 0); // 25 frames per second
// 42.8150000000023 ms
// 42.1600000000035 ms
// 44.8150000000023 ms
// 41.8299999999872 ms
// 43.195000000007 ms
// 41.7250000000058 ms
// 42.1349999999802 ms
// 43.0950000000012 ms
```

You can simulate any frame rate pretty easily now

```
loop(framesPerSecond(0.5), 0); // 1 frame per 2 seconds
// 2001.58 ms
// 2002.705 ms
// 2005.9 ms
// 2001.665 ms
// 2002.59 ms
// 2006.165 ms
```

> **Note:** `framesPerSecond` will not be very accurate when `draw` takes any significant amount of time to complete. You could improve this by measuring the duration it takes for `draw` to run each cycle and subtracting that from the `fps` delay.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that calculates fibonacci (limited to a max in order to not kill the browser), and call it between other functions:

```
function fibo(max) {
    var x = 0;
    for (var i = 0, j = 1, k = 0; k < max; i = j, j = x, k++) {
        x = i + j;
    }
}
```

and then just call it between your other function calls:

```
doSomething();
fibo(15);
doSomethingElse();
fibo(15);
doSomethingElseElse();
fibo(15);
```